# SSAS Cube Duplicate Cannot Load Model

Tags: sql-server, ssas

**Issue**
Primary developer on BI Model (SSAS Cube) can no longer access the model.
When they try to open the tabular designer in SSAS they get the following error message.

[image: Error Duplicate ID]

The interesting thing is, when I go to track down that data issue, I can't find it in the source table or in the model on that table.

Another interesting thing is I can still open the model, but he cannot.

We thought it might be permissions, but I have the same access as him, and I can open the tabular designer.

My next thought was since this is propagating as a data issue, maybe it's not looking at the right data source but there's only one data warehouse to connect to and again I cannot duplicate the error on my side, nor when I check the underlying tables does this record even exist.

The model in production (connected to SQL agent) works fine and has been running without a hitch.

How did his copy of the model get out of sync? Any ideas on what might be happening here? How can I fix this so he has access again? Unfortunately there's no version control of the model, can I pull the model down from production and have him access that?

If there's any questions I can further answer please ask and I will update.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a Process Clear on the dimension with the duplicate value, verifying the source data doesn't contain any duplicate values on the one side of the one-to-many relationship, then reprocessing the model?  Depending on the size, you could also does this on the entire model if it's small enough to allow this.  If you're unable to access the model directly, you can also send a processing command through SSMS or an Analysis Services Execute DDL Task or Processing Task in SSIS.

As far as pulling the model from production for him, you can make a backup of the production model and restore it over his version with the replace option.  The following commands are examples of a backup and restore.  This is using TMSL, which is for models at compatibility level 1200 or above.  If your model is below this level, you'll use XMLA.

```
{
"backup": {
"database": "YourSSASDatabaseName",
"file": "C:\\File Path\\YourModelName.abf",
"allowOverwrite": false,
"applyCompression": true
    }
}
```

Note the allowOverWrite option:

```
   {
    "restore": {
    "database": "TargetSSASDatabaseToRestoreTo",
    "file": "C:\\File Path\\YourModelName.abf",
    "allowOverwrite": true,
    "readWriteMode": "readWrite"
      }
    }
```

Comment: There is no duplicate in the table and we can get the model open